# Best way to get output from another PHP file as a variable

Tags: php

I need to include the output/result of a PHP file in another file.

I found info online about using curl to do this, but it doesn't seem to work so well, and so efficiently.

This is my current code:

```
function curl_load($url){
    curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

$url = "http://domain.com/file.php";
$output = curl_load($url);

echo "output={$output}";
```

Any recommendations on what I can use to make this more efficient/work better?

I'm looking for whichever method would be the fastest and most efficient, since I have a bunch of connections/users that will be using this file constantly to get updated information.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific what you mean by "efficient/work better"? If you are talking about the extra time your PHP script takes to execute then that is somewhat unavoidable as the PHP engine needs time to download `$url`.

Comment: Updated the original question... Thanks!

Comment: if you want to avoid redownloading the file for every single user/request, then you should be caching the contents of the downloaded file for e.g. 5 minutes, by writing to a local file the contents of the downloaded file. Subsequent requests would be served from that local file instead of via cURL/file_get_contents. Though that would be out of the context of your original question (Google should find heaps of answers on how to do that), and also depends on how often you have updates in that remote file.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense - it probably should update every 5 minutes or so.
Can you point me in the right direction on how to do that?
Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the other file functions in PHP. You will need a function that will let you write to files (like how file_get_contents lets you read from files). There are a couple of ways to remember when if the cache file was updated more than 5 minutes ago, one way I can think of is to check the time the cache file was modified, and do some datetime calculations with it. Good luck!

Comment: See below - I ended up using an include statement to include the other file...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up going with a PHP include statement, to include the other file.
I had forgotten to mention that the file was local, and this seems to make the most sense at this point - instead of echoing the result in the other PHP file, I'm just setting the result as a variable, and then pulling that variable in my other file.

Comment: That is the one detail which you forgot to state, and everyone here forgot to ask. Guess everyone got misled by the fact you mentioned curl in your question.

Answer (score 3):

file_get_contents() may suitable for you

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
```

you can also use the file() or fopen()

```
$homepage = file('http://www.example.com/');

$homepage = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

Comment: I had tried that as well before this, and had problems with it, and the curl method supposedly was better, though it might not be...

Comment: Any idea which method is better/more efficient?